# How do I scale down and scale up on a visual proportions of specific variables in a stacked barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, data-visualization, stacked-chart

I'm attempting to make a bar chart that shows the different taxonomic abundance proportions I have in my different sample sets. However, since my samples are dominated mainly by the phylum "Proteobacteria", the phyla that comprise much smaller proportions in my samples aren't really visible in the plot. What I would like to have is the to have the visual proportion of proteobacteria scaled down so that the other taxonomic abundances can be scaled up for the differences to be viewed more easily. Right now I'm not sure which function to use to alter the scales of individual variables. I'd also like to add gaps in between the blocks so that each variable can be seen more clearly. I know this can be done for `position = 'dodge'` using the `width` argument, but I haven't found an equivalent for `'position = 'stack'`. I'd appreciate any advice or suggestions to improve my code and plot!

```
ggplot(En.PhyBac.NoC.RelAb.tidy.100, aes(x = RelAbBySamType, y = 1,
                                         fill = as.factor(phylum))) + 
          geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +
          facet_wrap(SampleType ~ ., ncol = 1,
                     labeller = labeller(SampleType = sample_types),
                     strip.position = 'right') + 
          scale_fill_manual(name = 'Phyla', values = phylum_col) + 
          theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
                panel.spacing.x = unit(0.5, 'cm'),
                panel.spacing.y = unit(0.5, 'cm'),
                legend.box.spacing = unit(0.5, 'cm'),
                legend.background = element_rect(fill = 'grey90'))
```

[image: The link to the plot image is here.]

Comment: One crazy option is to omit the Proteobacteria group and plot the rest but keep their overall percentages (akin exploding pie chart). As it stands, all I see in that graph is a lot of purple.

Comment: Another option is to limit the x-axis by `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(75, 100), oob = scales::squish)` and explain in text somewhere that you've shortened the x axis.

Comment: Thanks @teunbrand! I used `oob = scales::squish_infinite` instead to adjust the scale, but I wouldn't have found that out if you hadn't mentioned the `oob` argument!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
geom_bar (stat = 'identity', position = 'stack', width=1)
```

Or whichever unit you find suitable